# How to replace multiple substrings in a Pandas series using a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas series of strings. I want to make multiple replacements to multiple substrings *per row*, see:

```
testdf = pd.Series([
    'Mary went to school today',
    'John went to hospital today'
])
to_sub = {
    'Mary': 'Alice',
    'school': 'hospital',
    'today': 'yesterday',
    'tal': 'zzz',
}
testdf = testdf.replace(to_sub, regex=True)  # does not work (only replaces one instance per row)
print(testdf)
```

In the above case, the desired output is:

```
Alice went to hospital yesterday.
John went to hospizzz yesterday.
```

where note the first row had three substitutions from the dictionary.

How can I perform this efficiently apart from doing this row by row (in a for loop)?

I tried `df.replace(...)` as many other answers in other questions but that only replaces a single substring, the result is like: `Alice went to school today`, where `school` and `today` weren't substituted..

Another thing to note is that the substitutions should happen **all at once** for any single row. (see the `hospital` in the first row isn't substituted a *second* time to `hospizzz` which would be *wrong*).

Comment: What version of Pandas you are using?

Comment: @pygo I am using 0.24.1

Comment: Ahhh ... that should work then may be some bug with the new Version, it works perfectly to me.

Comment: You sure you want to do this ? which involved o(n*m) , If you df is big it will become very slow .

Comment: @Wen-Ben Who are you addressing? What alternative would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
#Borrowed from an external website
def multipleReplace(text, wordDict):
    for key in wordDict:
        text = text.replace(key, wordDict[key])
    return text

print(testdf.apply(lambda x: multipleReplace(x,to_sub)))

0    Alice went to hospital yesterday
1     John went to hospital yesterday
```

**EDIT**

Using the dictionary as below mentioned comments:

```
to_sub = {
'Mary': 'Alice',
'school': 'hospital',
'today': 'yesterday',
'tal': 'zzz'
}

testdf.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([to_sub.get(i, i) for i in x.split()]))
```

Outputs:

```
0    Alice went to hospital yesterday
1     John went to hospital yesterday
```

Comment: hi, thanks. the issue with replacing 1-by-1 in a 'for' loop is that later substitutions might replace the earlier substitutions. Try including another `'tal': 'zzz'` in the to_sub dictionary. Then row 0 would become `hospizzz` which is wrong (row 1 would have `hospizzz` but that is correctly substituted)

Comment: @ksgj1 how big is the df?

Comment: something like 200k to 500k rows

Comment: looks good, thanks. I'll leave this qn up a while more before deciding the accept

Comment: Sure..!! No problem

Comment: should it be hospizzz?

Comment: @Wen-Ben i think exact match replacement was what was needed initially. :) Hospital for the first row and hospizz for the second sounded kinda inefficient to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is working for me in panadas 23.0 version...

### Given DataFrame:

```
>>> testdf
0      Mary went to school today
1    John went to hospital today
dtype: object
```

### Values Which needs to be replaced.

```
>>> replace_values = {'Mary': 'Alice', 'school': 'hospital', 'today': 'yesterday'}
```

### Resulted Outcome:

```
>>> testdf.replace(replace_values, regex=True)
0    Alice went to hospital yesterday
1     John went to hospital yesterday
dtype: object
```

### Another example With Desired Result :

Including Partial string ('tal': 'zzz') manulation with replace ..

```
>>> replace_values = {'Mary': 'Alice', 'school': 'hospital', 'today': 'yesterday', 'tal': 'zzz'}
>>> testdf.replace(replace_values, regex=True)
0    Alice went to hospizzz yesterday
1     John went to hospizzz yesterday
dtype: object
```

Comment: @pygo not working in 0.24.1 (just checked). also anyway, I don't want row 0's substituted "hospital" to become "hospizzz". each row should only be substituted based on the original string (which was "... school ..."