# Change substring in a column from a dict (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've got 2 dataframe from 2 excel sheets (in the same file). I want to change the name of each molecules in the first sheet [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Mkm.png) with the "official id" from a database present in the second sheet [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DylCu.png).

[screen first dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Mkm.png)

[screen second dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DylCu.png)

```
import pandas as pd
reactions = pd.read_excel ("/Users/Python/reactions.xlsx")

molecules = pd.read_excel ("/Users/Python/reactions.xlsx" , 
                          sheet_name= 'METS')

d = molecules.set_index('MOLID')['MOLNAME'].to_dict()
#not work 
reactions['EQUATION'] = reactions['EQUATION'].str.replace('\d+','').replace(d)
```

I have the old/new molecules name in a dictionary, that I also created from the 2nd sheet:

`d`

And it is like

`{....'glucose[c]': 'glc_D',
 'glucose[s]': 'glc_D',
 'glucose[x]': 'glc_D', ....}`

In the first database the column where I want to change the molecules name is call EQUATION and it is like: "ATP[c] + glucose[c] => ADP[c] + glucose6phosphate[c]"
I try change with this code, it doesn't error, but the molecules in my dataframe haven't changed.

Thank you for the time

Comment: This should work: `reactions['EQUATION'].str.replace('\d+','').map(d)`

Comment: Hey John, better if you show us something that resembles your data [mcve]

Comment: I have try also the command .map but it doesn't work, the column becomes NaN for each line

Comment: Hy @Datanovice i have just upload the two screen of the dataframe

Comment: are you able to show us your expected input & output in a textual format, we need to copy your data into our IDE's to test see what works and doesnt.

Comment: The print from the second dataframe and the variable names that you are using don't match, can you provide the correct code/dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to replace multiple substrings in a Pandas series using a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958423/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-in-a-pandas-series-using-a-dictionary)

I think if you adjust the code to something like this you are able to do it

```
 reactions['EQUATION'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([d.get(i, i) for i in x.split()]))
```